# php script to scrape amazon website

Tags: php, web-scraping

i wrote a php script to scrape the amazon website to get the price of an item.i provide the ASIN number,but the price is not getting displayes.
this is the php script:

(Prezzo|Precio|Price|Prix Amazon|Preis):?\([^\

the output:
The price for amazon.com/dp/B01CHCKY8Q is 0.00

Comment: Try a freelancing site. Stack Overflow doesn't do your work for you.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

They've open sourced the sdk and the documentation is in detail. Heres the GitHub link - https://github.com/uber/rides-android-sdk/blob/master/README.md